# Find changes to android's native calendar

Tags: android, calendar, listener

I am writing an app that needs to fetch the latest changes to android's native calendar since the last time I performed such a "sync" operation.

I am also accessing other content such as the contacts. Here I can reliably check whether the VERSION column of a RawContact changes over time, however I fail to find similar options for calendar events.

Registering a ContentObserver only triggers once something changes, but does not yield the rows that changed. I thought about querying the Calendar.Events ContentProvider for any rows that have the DIRTY column set to 1, however I would be at the mercy of Google's sync adapter, which might potentially be called more quickly (?) than my query is being processed.

Likewise when no network connection is present on the android device, the dirty columns will remain 1, which yields unsuitable results for my use-case.

Is there a better way to listen for changes to the native android calendar which returns correct results, even when no network connection is present?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there is no simple way to do this.

Here is how I worked around this issue:
I am keeping a local cache database for contacts that I found the last time I queried the database. Whenever a change occurs (notified by a call to ContentObserver::onChange()) I compare the entries in my cache database to those of CalendarContract.Contacts using a CursorJoiner.

Ids that exist in both cursors need to be compared for changes. To do so I generated a hash for every content, which i stored alongside the contact Id in my cache db.

IDs only provided by the ContentProvider represent new contacts since the last "sync", while IDs only contained in the cache DB are deleted contacts.

Once the differences are obtained, the cache database needs to be updated accordingly.